# Delete nested fields where value is X in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

So I have a collection of animals that looks something like this:

```
{ "collection":
  [
      {   "name":"cow",
      "parts": [
          {"part_name":"legs"},
          {"part_name":"rumen"},
          {"part_name":"tail"},
          {"part_name":"nostrils"}
      ]
      },
      {   "name":"sheep",
      "parts": [
          {"part_name":"legs"},
          {"part_name":"rumen"},
          {"part_name":"tail"},
          {"part_name":"nostrils"}
      ]
      },
      {   "name":"goat",
      "parts": [
          {"part_name":"legs"},
          {"part_name":"rumen"},
          {"part_name":"tail"},
          {"part_name":"nostrils"}
      ]
      },
      {   "name":"dog",
      "parts": [
          {"part_name":"ears"},
          {"part_name":"nipples"},
          {"part_name":"legs"},
          {"part_name":"nostrils"}
      ]
      }
  ]
}
```

I don't like the part_name "rumen", so I want to write a delete statement that deletes only the nested fields where the value is "rumen", ie:

```
delete from animals where parts.part_name = 'rumen';
```

But that's not the way to go about it. How do I achieve this?

EDIT: animals table explained (parts is a repeated field):

```
|   animal_name   |            parts.part_name           |
+-----------------+--------------------------------------+
|       cow       |                  legs                |
|                 |                  rumen               |
|                 |                  tail                |
|                 |                 nostrils             |
+-----------------+--------------------------------------+
|      sheep      |                  legs                |
|                 |                  rumen               |
|                 |                  tail                |
|                 |                 nostril              |
+-----------------+--------------------------------------+
|       goat      |                  legs                |
|                 |                  rumen               |
|                 |                  tail                |
|                 |                 nostrils             |
+-----------------+--------------------------------------+
|        dog      |                  ears                |
|                 |                 nipples              |
|                 |                  legs                |
|                 |                 nostrils             |
+-----------------+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you show us the structure of the table? The json presented doesn't match the expectation `parts.part_name`.

Comment: done, I hope this clarifies things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot `delete` nested field. What you can do is `update` all the records that do have `rumen` with new array value excluding `rumen`. I'm not quite sure about your schema, but it should be something like this

```
update tmp.collection c
-- assign new array value, for which we select everything but 'rumen'.
set parts = array(select * from c.parts where part_name <> 'rumen')
-- we only care about the rows that have 'rumen' in the first place.
where exists (select 1 from c.parts where part_name = 'rumen');
```